# How concurrency works with anonymous functions ? go

Tags: go

I'm trying to loop through a list (e.g. sql rows) and fire go routines for each row. The issue is that the values passed to the function are not evaluated at the runtime so depending by how much time the function takes to execute it may use whatever value is on one of the  next(s) rows instead the current one.

I'm aware that I could extract  the function in a normal one and pass the arguments  but I still want to share some global variables(to avoid many function arguments) thus the need to use an  anonymous function.
  Still it's also confusing to me that the anonymous function takes variables from the environment while it's being executed because as far as I understand it is supposed to be executed in a separate routines just like & in unix programs, the communication being done only through channels.

The question is how do I make the anonymous function to receive a copy of `vc` and use it during runtime ?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"


type mystruct struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func main() {

    vc := mystruct{}
    vc.i = 1
    vc.s = "hi"
    gl := "this is global"
    for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {

    go func() {
        vc.i++
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

        fmt.Printf("row specific is %v, global is %v", vc, gl)
    }()

    }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

}
```

[Play here](http://play.golang.org/p/5x5HU0HToh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't understand what you're trying to achieve, however, if your only goal is to make a copy of the variable, you can just pass it to the go func like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/_PmY15EZOd):

```
for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
    go func(vc mystruct) {
        vc.i++
        //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

        fmt.Printf("row specific is %v, global is %v\n", vc, gl)
    }(vc)
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I actually did...in the end

Answer (score 2):

The code is accessing the same struct from multiple goroutines .
You need to protect the struct with a mutex to govern the access to its value.
Also you need to wait for  all the goroutines to finish. Time.Sleep alone will not guarantee that. Use a Wait group. Here is a working example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "strconv"
import "sync"

type mystruct struct {
    i int
    s string
    m sync.Mutex
}

func main() {

    vc := mystruct{}
    vc.i = 1
    vc.s = "hi"

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            vc.m.Lock()
            defer vc.m.Unlock()
            defer wg.Done()
            vc.i++
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
            vc.s = "good bye" + strconv.Itoa(vc.i)
            fmt.Printf("%v \n", vc)
        }()

    }

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/K6rnQQSA1c

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but isn't mutex a blocker ? if vc.m is locked I assume it can't be used by the other go routines. until one unlocks it.

Comment: The execution seems synchronous to me. You can clearly see that if you increase the sleep time (e.g. to one second instead of 1 ms)

Comment: Your problem is the closure. You're not receiving a copy - you're receiving a closed-over instance.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I've added an answer below. Basically I just copy it the struct within the anonymous function. I'm still wondering if it's the right way to do it. Concerning the answer above I don't understand the upvote because it basically blocks the go routine. There is no concurrency thus the "go" keyword is useless. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're not wrong - but you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what you're trying to achieve via the use of an anonymous method. You need copies or locks. You can't be lock free here unless you completely go channel-based.. which you haven't hinted at being a possibility.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks for taking time to respond. The root of misunderstanding was how Go keyword actually works. I thought it isolates the functions like in a  separate thread so that the communication could be done only through channels which doesn't seem true. The go routines even share information so it's something that I didn't expect http://play.golang.org/p/yULeZDgRhI

Answer (score -2):

It seems the only way is to create the struct within the anonymous function and copy the closure value . See the code below. As @fabrizioM advised you should use wg if you need synchronisation. However the question was not about that thus I don't include the wg.

Still I'm not sure if it's safe as the the copy of `vc`  may take some time so edits/ improvements are still welcome

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

type mystruct struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func main() {

    vc := mystruct{}
    vc.i = 1
    vc.s = "hi"

    for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {

        go func() {
            vc2 := vc
            vc.i++
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

            fmt.Printf("%v\n", vc2)
        }()

    }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

}
```

[Click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/jTFBX3kFnS)

Comment: This is no different from any other language that has the concept of closures. You must copy the value in its entirety within the scope of the anonymous method - otherwise the method will be referencing stale data. The only other option is to protect access to it via the method provided in the answer above with a concurrency primitive such as a mutex.

Comment: yeah, it seems the only way to isolate the go routines (and obviously run them concurrently) is to use normal functions and pass the global variables along with the specific data as function arguments. The anonymous function is quite against any concurrency as even the variables declared within the anonymous function are shared with other go routines of the same function. So basically if one go routine is "slower" at any time it may take the value from another routine as it runs instead its own and the result would make no sense.

Comment: You still haven't removed the race condition in your answer. You can use the `-race` flag to see this.  i.e. `go run -race main.go` (if your go code is in main.go)